Calendar invites not showing
I have three iPhones in my family and it seems that none of them are able to receive/send calendar invitations. If I send an invitation between any of the phones, none of them seem to receive it. I looked a bit on the forums, on Reddit and on the Apple support website, but everything seems alright.
All phones are running iOS 17.5.1.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

The latest iOS on my iPhone is 16.7.8 because it's old. The latest iOS on your iPhones maybe much newer as you may have newer models. However, you need to update your question with exactly what version you are running, otherwise this question would have no relevance in 12 months time after numerous updates. The behaviour you are experiencing may be a version specific problem.

@AndyGriffiths Fixed. Thanks!
